# get and share page URL - webView android

Tags: android

I want to **get** the URL of current page in my webView and **share** it. 
Below are the codes for getting page URL and sharing the package name; I don't know how to use them together.

**get page URL-**

```
String url = webView.getUrl();
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        clipboard.setText(url);
    } else {
        android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData
                .newPlainText("text label", url);
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
    }
```

**share package name**

```
findViewById(R.id.exitdlg).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
            "http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="
                    + "com.air.blahblah");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share..."));
```

I am new to android, any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the url with below code:

```
String url = webView.getUrl();
```

So use the same url in sharing intent as below:

```
findViewById(R.id.exitdlg).setVisibility(View.GONE);
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,url); // your above url
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share..."));
```

Hope I answered your question.